# IndentationError: unindent does not match any outer indentation level (request module)

Tags: python

```
import requests
import json


session = requests.session()

headers = {
    'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate, br',
    'Accept-Language': 'en-US,en;q=0.9',
    'Upgrade-Insecure-Requests': '1',
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/64.0.3282.167 Safari/537.36',
    'Accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8',
}


def ATCbuilder():
    global session
    response = session.get("https://www.glidesoftwares.com/products.json", headers=headers)
    data = json.loads(response.text)
    stock = data['products'][0]['variants'][0]['available']
    variant = data['products'][0]['variants'][0]['id']
    atclink = 'https://www.glidesoftwares.com/cart/{}:1'.format(variant)
    print(atclink)
```

> IndentationError: unindent does not match any outer indentation level

why??

Comment: Can you provide line number of the error? Confirm you have no mixed indents (spaces/tabs).

Comment: When i copy the code and run it, it works fine

Comment: Line error is 21 @zoran119

Comment: @BOi that is really weird, wonder why its not running on my computer

Answer (score 0):

It's very likely that there are spaces AND tabs in your indentations.
Replace all spaces with tabs in all of your code. Try copying this and running again maybe:

```
import requests
import json


session = requests.session()

headers = {
    'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate, br',
    'Accept-Language': 'en-US,en;q=0.9',
    'Upgrade-Insecure-Requests': '1',
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/64.0.3282.167 Safari/537.36',
    'Accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8',
}


def ATCbuilder():
    global session
    response = session.get("https://www.glidesoftwares.com/products.json", headers=headers)
    data = json.loads(response.text)
    stock = data['products'][0]['variants'][0]['available']
    variant = data['products'][0]['variants'][0]['id']
    atclink = 'https://www.glidesoftwares.com/cart/{}:1'.format(variant)
    print(atclink)
```

If it doesn't work, I'm happy to delete this answer.